# Establish Schedule is missing on Opportunity Products

Tags: opp-lineitemschedule

Even after enabling "Quantity Schedules" and "Revenue Schedules" under Schedule setup, I am unable to see establish button on Products.

I am also validating that the Quantity and Revenue Scheduling enabled Checkboxes are checked in the products, but I still do not see this Establish Schedule section in opportunity products.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "Schedules" related list to your page layout(s) for the Opportunity Product object. That related list is where you will find the "Establish Schedule" button.